# Manipulating Excel Data using Visual C#

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I need to set/insert hyperlinks for a range of values in an Excel sheet from my program written in Visual C#.
 I am using "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" and no third party Excel tools.

I have URLs in string format with me in the program which need to show up as Hyperlinks in the Excel workbook.

Any ideas on how this can be implemented? I did not see any familiar feature in Excel.Range which I could use. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Ivar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Hyperlinks.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.hyperlinks.add%28office.11%29.aspx)?

You can add a hyperlink to a range of cells (after setting the text content).

Comment: Used excelApplication.Hyperlinks.Add method and it worked great. Thanks for the suggestion!!